# How can I create this Popup and check to see if user has Allowed App?

Tags: facebook, popup

How would I create a popup on my website that shows up (that blocks the website's content) only if the user hasn't yet allowed my Facebook app? The popup should not come up if the user has already allowed the app, and the popup should have a button for users to allow the application and then go away when the user does allow the application.

For an example, see [here](http://sofunnyhaha.com).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [FB.getLoginStatus](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

That page pretty much explains it... If you get `not_authorized` then have a button to authorize your app.

If you get `unknown` have a button to log in to facebook then recheck

If you get `connected` show your page.

Comment: Thanks so much! Can you put html right inside the else/else if statements?

Comment: Umm I mean you can add it using javascript... if you don't understand how javascript and html and php all combine together to make a webpage, it is a little early to be messing with the facebook api stuff.  Try some basic tutorials to get started wtih.

Comment: Unfortunately I am inexperienced when it comes to programming...however between my brother and I, we were able to implement a Facebook app into my website with an action word and everything that posts to the users' timeline when they view our pages (with og tags). So we got that far.

But getting back to my question, Could I create a popup using Javascript where the comments are in the code (within the if/if else statement)?

Comment: Yes. You should be able to do that.